# Weird compile-time error on Select() and ToList() LINQ methods

Tags: c#, extension-methods, compile-time

I have a few simple lines of code in a WPF project which give me compilation errors.

```
var resourceNames = new List<string> { "cmbItem1", "cmbItem2", "cmbItem3", "cmbItem4" };

var comboBoxItems = resourceNames.Select(id => (string)FindResource(id)).ToList();

// other code
```

The compilation error text is

> ***Error 2 The type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.***

Why have I reference that assembly? I don't use any type from System.Windows.Forms.Control!

If I rewrite the code to make static methods invocations instead of extension methods invocations, it works fine:

```
var resourceNames = new List<string> { "cmbItem1", "cmbItem2", "cmbItem3", "cmbItem4" };

var comboBoxItems = Enumerable.Select(resourceNames, id => (string)FindResource(id));
comboBoxItems = Enumerable.ToList(comboBoxItems);

// other code
```

Why is it so? What am I doing wrong?

***UPD1:***
[image: An error is in the list.]

***UPD2: THE ANSWER***

I and my colleague have investigated the project and found that the reason of the problem. Here are several facts about our visual studio solution:

1. The problematic code resides in project called Flyer2. That project has a reference to another project called Global.
2. The project Global has several classes which provide global accessible extension methods.
3. One of the extension method has a restriction for a generic type in where clause. The restriction says that the generic type must be an descendant of System.Windows.Control... For some reason existence of a such method produces the compile-time error I've described...

Here is the code of the extension method and the class defining it:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Global
{
    public static class ControlExtensions
    {
        // If I remove the where-clause, the code problem disappears!
        public static T FindParentByType<T>(this Control parentControl) where T : Control

        {
            var currentControl = parentControl != null ? parentControl.Parent : null;
            while (currentControl != null)
            {
                if (currentControl is T)
                    return (T)currentControl;
                currentControl = currentControl.Parent;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get any compilation error on compiling first two lines

Comment: Are you sure? Cuz, your code is working fine on my end :S

Comment: I've attached the screenshot of the VS2010.

Comment: What does it say when you hover over '.select' in VS? Maybe it has incorrectly resolved it as 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does have a select method.

Comment: Well, I've just found the reason of that strange behaviour. I'm going to write the description in a few minutes.